# mod_rewrite - inject title in the start of a url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL structure like:
/index.php?id=1&a=2&b=3
or
/index.php?id=29&d=5&e=6&f=8

The variables passed changes depending on which page you're on.

I'm looking for a rewrite rule that will allow me to do:

/page-name/?id=1&a=2&b=3
or
/page-name/?id=29&d=5&e=6&f=8

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `page-name` is a literal string (a constant)? Or does it stand for individual titles of pages?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will pass the query string (the URL part after `?`) to the index.php / existing files will not be processed in any way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

It assumes you're not interested in what is the title and it completely ignores it.